# How to convert a list into its elements

Tags: scheme, racket

This must be very easy to accomplish but I am new to racket and dont know how:

I have a list (1 2 3 4) and would like to convert it into (1)(2)(3)(4)

Or is there a way to build it as (1)(2)(3)(4). I am using

```
 cons '(element) call-function
```

to build it inside a function (recursively)

Comment: What do you mean by (1)(2)(3)(4)? 4 separate values? I'm not sure it is possible if their number is not fixed. Or a list where each element is a list with one number, meaning ((1) (2) (3) (4))? Or anything else?

Comment: I think I mean 4 separate values.

Comment: Most you could get is `'((1)(2)(3)(4))`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
(map list '(1 2 3 4))
```

Comment: Or even `(apply values (map list '(1 2 3 4)))`.

Answer (score 2):

From your text, I see that you do `'(element)`. Problem with that is that everything which is quoted is never anything but what you see. Thus if `element` happens to be a variable it won't be expanded because of the quote.

The right way to get a list with one element would be to use `list`. eg. `(list element)` to get whatever the variable `element` to be the one element in your list. However, you won't need this in a roll-your-own recursive procedure:

```
(define (listify lst)
  (if (null? lst)                  ; if lst is null we are done
      '()                          ; evaluate to the empty list
      (cons (list (car lst))       ; else we make a list with the first element
            (listify (cdr lst))))) ; and listify the rest of the list too
```

Most of the procedure now is facilitating going through the argument, but since it's a common thing to do we can use higher order procedures with foldr so that you only concentrating on what is going to happen with the element in this chain in correspondence with the rest of the process:

```
(define (listify lst)
  (foldr (lambda (e acc)
           (cons (list e) ; chain this element wrapped in a list 
                 acc))    ; with the result from the rest of the list
         '()              ; initiate with an empty list
         lst))            ; go through lst
```

Of course, since we do something with each element in a list and nothing fancy by using `map` we only need to supply what to do with each element rather telling how to join the chains in the list together as well.

```
(define (listify lst)
  (map list lst))      ; make a new list by applying a list of each element
```

It's actually a single argument version of `zip`:

```
(require srfi/1)
(zip '(1 2 3 4))        ; ==> ((1) (2) (3) (4))
(zip '(1 2 3) '(a b c)) ; ==> ((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))
```

There you go. As simple as it can get.